# How to wrap pairs of values inside div?

Tags: html, handlebars.js

We have a list of items that we want to render with a handlebars template so that every pair is wrapped in a div. Here is an example of the JSON data structure:

```
var exampleData = [
    { Label : "Apple" },
    { Label : "Banana" },
    { Label : "Cherry" },
    { Label : "Damson" },
    { Label : "EggPlant"},
    { Label : "Fig" },
    { Label : "Grape" }
];
```

We want to wrap the data in lots of two. For example:

```
<div class="WRAPPER">
    <b class="EACH">
        <a>Apple</a>
    </b>
    <b class="EACH">
        <a>Banana</a>
    </b>
</div>
<div class="WRAPPER">
    <b class="EACH">
        <a>Cherry</a>
    </b>
    <b class="EACH">
        <a>Damson</a>
    </b>
</div>
<div class="WRAPPER">
    <b class="EACH">
        <a>EggPlant</a>
    </b>
    <b class="EACH">
        <a>Fig</a>
    </b>
</div>
<div class="WRAPPER">
    <b class="EACH">
        <a>Grape</a>
    </b>
    <b class="EACH">
        <a></a>
    </b>
</div>
```

Each fruit in the above example is a value from the data structure, everything else is template that we want to define as HTML.

Furthermore, if the data has an odd number of values, we would like to render a blank set of tags (as shown in the last `a` tag above.

What is the correct way to template this kind of pattern in handlebars.js? Alternatively is there a specific helper that can achieve this end?

Comment: Please show us what your data structure looks like as that tells us what handlebars syntax could be used to iterate through it.  Also, please make it clear which "VALUE" is what from your data structure.

Comment: added data structure and additional info.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your data format so it is structured in pairs on a single object, then this would be fairly easy.

```
var exampleData = [
    { Label1 : "Apple", Label2 : "Banana" },
    { Label1 : "Cherry", Label2 : "Damson" },
    { Label1 : "EggPlant", Label2 : "Fig" },
    { Label : "Grape", Label2: "" }
];

{{! Iterate top level array }}
{{#each this}}
    <div class="WRAPPER">
        <b class="EACH">
            <a>{{Label1}}</a>
        </b>
        <b class="EACH">
            <a>{{Label2}}</a>
        </b>
     </div>    
{{/each}}
```

Or, you could organize the data into sub-arrays that would each be expanded:

```
var exampleData = [
    [{ Label : "Apple" }, { Label : "Banana" }],
    [{ Label : "Cherry" }, { Label : "Damson" }],
    [{ Label : "EggPlant"}, { Label : "Fig" }],
    [{ Label : "Grape"}, { Label : "" }]
];

{{! Iterate top level array }}
{{#each this}}
    <div class="WRAPPER">
        {{! Iterate each sub-array for however many elements there are}}
        {{#each this}}
            <b class="EACH">
                <a>{{Label}}</a>
            </b>
        {{/each}}
     </div>    
{{/each}}
```

Both of these approaches require a little preprocessing of the data before you pass it to the template to organize the data to match the capabilities of the templates, but then it lets you use generic template features as is without writing custom helpers or generating HTML directly from your javascript or helper (which is generally the point of using the template system in the first place).

I find handlebars a lot easier to use if I make the data fit the template capabilities and features rather than try to do it the other way around and it's usually a very small mount of code to reorganize the data.

---

Of course, if the label is really your only data, then you don't need the wrapper objects.

```
var exampleData = [
    ["Apple" ,"Banana"],
    ["Cherry" "Damson"],
    ["EggPlant", "Fig"],
    ["Grape", ""]
];

{{! Iterate top level array }}
{{#each this}}
    <div class="WRAPPER">
        {{! Iterate each sub-array for however many elements there are}}
        {{#each this}}
            <b class="EACH">
                <a>{{this}}</a>
            </b>
        {{/each}}
     </div>    
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Yes, realise the data can be massaged prior to templating but wondered if there is a way of doing it just using handlebars (e.g. without remapping the source data).

Comment: @BenFrain - Not that I'm aware of without writing a helper that generated this HTML rather than have it coming from the template.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these ingredients can help you to come to a nice solution.

Within the each you can access the index of the array like:

```
{{#each this}}
  The current index :{{@index}}
{{/each}}
```

It is also possible to show a specific item in the array like this:

```
{{arr.1.label}}
```

In combination with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mpetrovich/wMmHS/) excellent math helper you should be enable to do the job.